# Why do different android devices use different amounts of memory to load images?

Tags: java, android, image, memory-management, android-image

I'm making a game with a friend and we need to load a lot of images, so I've been trying to figure out how to determine what resolution my images should be by understanding how much memory they take up. I've been running tests on several android devices to load as many images into memory as possible before crashing and it seems that different devices can load an arbitrary amount of images. It really bums me out because there doesn't seem to be any reason for it.

To my understanding, the amount of memory an image should take in memory is the width x height x the number of bytes required for the color. In my tests, I've used 100x100x2 since I'm using 16-bit coloring for non-transparent images. That means it should take approximately 20000 bytes of memory per image, or roughly 20KB. I've also enabled the large heap but tests with the normal heap scale the same way. Test results are very consistent, I've run them a few times on each device with usually the exact same results.

On my phone, which has 256MB for the large heap, I can load 4973 of these images which should be approximately 99.46MB. On a friends tablet which has the exact same large heap size, he can load 11164 of these images which equates to 223.28MB.

On my tablet, which has a large heap size of 512MB, it loads 6117 images which is 122.34MB, and on my friends phone of the same large heap size it can only load 1479 images, the LEAST of any of them, which should only be 29.58MB. Why would a device with a heap size of 256MB be able to load 11164 images whereas a device with a heap size of 512MB be able to load only 1479 images?

All tests used the exact same images and 16-bit color format, but none of the results make any sense. Does resolution play a factor? If so, my friends phone and my tablet have very similar resolutions so that doesn't make any sense... It seems like the images take up different amounts of space on different devices for some reason. In the memory monitor, both devices with the large heap of 512MB used all of their memory up before crashing. That means the exact same program took different amounts of memory on two different devices, and all it does is load images. How can I determine how many images I can use on any device, or what resolution to use on which devices? Maybe I wrote my test wrong, or I misunderstood something?

here's the code for my test:

```
package foreal.testimagelimit;    

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bitmap [] bitmaps = new Bitmap[8675309];

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(new GameView(this));
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        int largeAmount = manager.getLargeMemoryClass();
        int normalAmount = manager.getMemoryClass();
        Log.d("foreal.testimagelimit", "Normal Memory: " + normalAmount);
        Log.d("foreal.testimagelimit","Large Memory: "+largeAmount);

        Resources r = this.getResources();
        for(int i=0; i<bitmaps.length; i++) {
            bitmaps[i] = loadBitmap(r.getDrawable(R.drawable.test100x100));
            Log.d("foreal.testimagelimit",(i+1)+" images loaded");
        }            
    }

    class GameView extends View {
        public GameView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap loadBitmap(Drawable sprite, Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig) {
        int width = sprite.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int height = sprite.getIntrinsicHeight();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, bitmapConfig);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        sprite.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
        sprite.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }

    public static Bitmap loadBitmap(Drawable sprite) {
        return loadBitmap(sprite, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it because they use different OS and hardware?

Comment: They do, but is there a predictable way to know how that affects how much space I can use? My phone and my friends tablet is api 16, my tablet is api 19 and my friends phone is api 21. The most up to date OS can load the least images for some reason.

Comment: Unless I got you wrong, may be should you think other way? do I need to keep these many images in memory? Are there any swapping techniques you can use? remember user could see only couple of pictures at any given point.

Comment: since we're developing a game, it's possible that we will need to reference a LOT of images really fast. In a worst case scenario in which most of our images need to be on screen, I'd think we could need roughly 3,000 because a lot of them are animated with only 15 frames. That said, we've tried lowering the resolution of our images and the test results scale similarly, but for the sake of making this post not too big I didn't want to include those. I still don't know how to predict whether my app will run on certain devices or not though, or whether I would need to lower my resolutions.

Comment: hmm, that is typical issue most of the developer face and I don't think there is concrete answer for this in Android world (pain comes with openness). I would still give a thought on any disk reading APIs could help you in simulating as if you are reading it from RAM.